# config.nt not exist in windows server 2008 64bit

Tags: nginx

i have a server with high traffic , it's about 20K request/sec at peak time
and 5~10k request/sec at normal time

but i have a serious problem
i install nginx in windows server 2008 standard edition 64bit , but i get this error message

> 2012/11/26 05:29:23 [error] 2496#2004: *3976 maximum number of descriptors supported by select() is 1024 while reading client request line, client: X.X.X.X, server: 0.0.0.0:8080

when i search , i found this problem is about dos application file handle limit , and i can be changed it on c:\windir\system32\Config.nt
but config.nt not exist
i also hear , in 64Bit os version , this file not exist 
so how can i change file handle in windows server 2008 - 64Bit ?